# First assignment, I've been trying for a while

Tags: python

I'm having trouble finding out what's the problem with my code. This is my first assignment from a course I'm taking. At first, I only did 11 points, I was able to fix the error shown then, and got 22 points, after that, I fixed it some more and got 56 points, but I can't go any further. This is my code:

```
import traceback
    

def calculator():
    
    # Get dog age
    dog_age = input("Input dog years: ")
    human_age = 0.0
    try:
        # Cast to float
        dog_age = float(dog_age)
        # If user enters negative number, print message
        if(dog_age < 0):
            print("Age can not be a negative number", dog_age)
        # Otherwise, calculate dog's age in human years
        elif(dog_age <= 1):
            human_age = 15
        elif(dog_age <= 2):
            human_age = dog_age * 12
        elif(dog_age <= 3):
            human_age = dog_age * 9.3
        elif(dog_age <= 4):
            human_age = dog_age * 8
        elif(dog_age <= 5):
            human_age = dog_age * 7.2
        else:
            human_age = dog_age *7.0
        print("\n \t \'The given dog age ", dog_age, "is", human_age, "in human years.'")
    except ValueError:
        print(dog_age, "is an invalid age")

calculator()
```

The errors that I get are:

### Received the below output from your program:

'
'The given dog age 1.0 is 15 in human years.'
'

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-21926286aa29> in <module>
      7 print("Received the below output from your program:\n---------------\n'{}'".format(checker.test_one(1)))
      8 checker.assert_almost_equal(
----> 9     checker.parse_dog_age(checker.test_one(1)),
     10     15,
     11     "Expected a 1 year old dog to be 15 in human years. Make sure your print statement is formatted as:\n\t \

~/work/release/module 1b/checker.py in parse_dog_age(msg)
     25 def parse_dog_age(msg):
     26     human_age = re.findall("\d+\.\d+ in human", msg)
---> 27     human_age = human_age[0].split(' ')[0].strip()
     28     return float(human_age)
     29 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

### Received the below output from your program:

'
'The given dog age 3.0 is 27.900000000000002 in human years.'
'

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-94d85e6cbf89> in <module>
      8 checker.assert_almost_equal(checker.parse_dog_age(checker.test_three(3)), 27.9,
      9             "Expected a 3 year old dog to be 27.9 in human years. Make sure your print statement is formatted as:\n\t \
---> 10     'The given dog age <input_value> is <calculated_age> in human years.'")
     11 print("Success!")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py in assertAlmostEqual(self, first, second, places, msg, delta)
    895                 places = 7
    896 
--> 897             if round(diff, places) == 0:
    898                 return
    899 

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: What is the original question?

Comment: is your code compact do you want sorry I dont understand

Comment: I think the problem is with the script used to check your code, as the errors are coming from code that isn't in your script.

Answer (score 0):

**The errors you're getting don't appear to be from your script.**

As I've commented, your script works perfectly fine, I don't see any issues. Your errors are from other files entirely:
`/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py` and `/work/release/module 1b/checker.py`.

Why are these programs running and causing errors? Are you submitting the code you wrote to these scripts? One hint from the errors is that the dog age ought to be an `int`, not a `float`:

> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 8 checker.assert_almost_equal(checker.parse_dog_age(checker.test_three(3)), 27.9,
> 9             "Expected a 3 year old dog to be 27.9 in human years. Make sure your print statement is formatted as:\n\t 
> ---> 10     'The given dog age <input_value> is <calculated_age> in human years.'")
> 11 print("Success!")

Whereas your print it as a float

> ' 'The given dog age 3.0 is 27.900000000000002 in human years.' '

Also, should there be quotes at both ends?

Your first error comes from this line:
`human_age = human_age[0].split(' ')[0].strip()`, where `human_age` appears to be either an empty string ot one comprised of only spaces.

In short, it's very hard to debug a program without knowing it's expected behaviour or source code. Consider posting an MRE.